# How to setInterval once inside foreach using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to set interval once for each slider element inside array when "if" statement is true but my code sets unlimited interval every time "if" statement is true. it is my js code:

```
const sliders = [realestateSlider,carsSlider,spectechnicSlider,motorcyclesSlider,partsSlider,beautySlider,clothesSlider,bestsellersSlider,topproductsSlider,salesSlider];

function checkIfIntoView(sliders){
    sliders.forEach(function(slider,index){
        if(slider.getBoundingClientRect().top <= window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.innerHeight){
            
           setInterval(function(){slider.scrollLeft += scrollWidth;},1000);
           
        }
    });
}

window.addEventListener('wheel',function(event){ checkIfIntoView(sliders); });
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout` instead.

Comment: @StackSlave setTimeout executes code once but i need to enable auto scrolling when element is into view because i need setInterval on each element only once.

Comment: The structure of code is not a problem i need just set intervals once on each slider element

Comment: Your structure ***is*** illogical.

Comment: @StackSlave could you provide a logical one?

Answer (score 0):

Since you call the checkIfIntoView function in event listener, event listner will tiger that function each and every time a on wheel event occur. So if you want to call the checkIfIntoView function once the wheel event triggered, use a Boolean variable.

```
let ran = false;
function checkIfIntoView(sliders){
   if (!ran) {
       ran = true
       sliders.forEach(function(slider,index){
           if(slider.getBoundingClientRect().top <= window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.innerHeight){
              setInterval(function(){slider.scrollLeft += scrollWidth;},1000);
           
           }
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: your code is checks code only once on wheel and then stops working but i have 7+ slider and need to keep code working till bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking... But if you want to scroll until `slider.getBoundingClientRect().top >= window.innerHeight` then you could write your function like this:

```
const sliders = [realestateSlider,carsSlider,spectechnicSlider,motorcyclesSlider,partsSlider,beautySlider,clothesSlider,bestsellersSlider,topproductsSlider,salesSlider];

function checkIfIntoView(sliders){
  sliders.forEach(function(slider,index){
    let interval = setInterval(function(slider){
      if (slider.getBoundingClientRect().top <= window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.innerHeight) {
        slider.scrollLeft += scrollWidth;
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
  }, 1000);
}

window.addEventListener('wheel',function(event){ checkIfIntoView(sliders); });
```

That way the interval will be cleared after the criteria is met. Keep in mind `setInterval` will continue to run until it is cleared via `clearInterval`

Comment: Yes you are not sure. I need if statement outside of setInterval function because first i need to check if element is into view and only then set interval once on that element

Comment: @stack, I think the code I posted does that in a different way than you are thinking. If the element is in view the sliders `scrollLeft` is incremented, other wise the interval is cleared and won't run. Does that make sense? In other words, an `interval` is created for each slider via `interval = setInterval(...`, but the slider only increments if the element is in view.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that those are all Elements in the sliders Array, maybe you're looking to do something like:

```
const sliders = [realestateSlider, carsSlider, spectechnicSlider, motorcyclesSlider, partsSlider, beautySlider, clothesSlider, bestsellersSlider, topproductsSlider, salesSlider];
onscroll = e=>{
  requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
    let b, t, l;
    for(let n of sliders){ // n is each node
      b = n.getBoundingClientRect(); t = b.top; l = b.left;
      if(t+b.height > -1 && t <= innerHeight && l+b.width > -1 && l <= innerWidth){
        console.log('in view');
      }
      else{
        console.log('not in view');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Note that you can always leave `window.` off of any property of `window`.

Comment: I am asking "How to setInterval once inside foreach using javascript
" Not "how to detect if element is into view"